# Запятая и опущенное "чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

"Я ищу тебя сказать о том-то". Нужна ли тут запятая? Подразумевается укороченное предложение: "Я ищу тебя, чтобы сказать о том-то".

Comment: Дословный перевод с английского?

Comment: @М_Г, нет, английский не при чём

Answer (score 2):

У предложения неверная грамматика, союз ЧТОБЫ нельзя пропускать.

Инфинитив может являться **обстоятельством цели**, но обычно для глаголов **положения или движения**: я пришёл сказать, я прилег отдохнуть.

Comment: Почему "чтобы нельзя пропускать"? Мне часто встречались варианты с двоеточием и тире вместо "чтобы".

Comment: Тире может обозначать пропущенное. Можно и точку поставить. Здесь нет никаких знаков, поэтому нарушена связь между членами предложения. Сочетание "пойти сказать" возможно, а "искать сказать" - нет.

Comment: А если в моём примере использовать тире или двоеточие, выражение жизнеспособно? Разумеется, как пример прямой речи.

Comment: Ни тире, ни двоеточие в БСП не могут передать значение цели. Тире  обозначает присоединительные или разделительные отношения (условие - событие, время - событие,  причина - следствие), а двоеточие имеет значение пояснения, изъяснения или   значение следствие - причина.

Comment: @Jasmin, а почему цель не может быть пояснением? И второе: откуда это ограничение глагола положением и движением? Синтаксически ситуации ведь одинаковы. Вспомнилось: "Зову тебя поговорить". Тут ни положение, ни движение. Чем "ищу" хуже?

Comment: 1) Поясняют уже что-то названное ранее, а здесь Вы просто обозначает цель. 2) Это ограничение  дается в учебниках по грамматике. 3) Зову тебя поговорить - авторский грамматический окказионализм. Если у Вас тоже стихи, то можете оставить.

Comment: Зову поговорить — стандартное употребление. СЛОВАРЬ
СОЧЕТАЕМОСТИ СЛОВ РУССКОГО под редакцией П. Н. ДЕНИСОВА, В. В. МОРКОВКИНА говорит: ЗВАТЬ: 
Позвать ко- го-л. с какой целью: (с неопр. ф.) ~ обедать, ужи-нать, завтракать, гулять.

Comment: Чего не скажешь о глаголе *искать* (не говорят "ищу что-то сделать")